# TWitter iOS 5 AddURL - what's displayed?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I'm using the `TWTeetComposeViewController` controls in iOS 5 like so: `TWTweetComposeViewController *twitController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];`

I need to add a URL but not have it show up as the URL text. Currently, if I have the following line of code:

```
[twitController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]]
```

The tweet will show a link to [apple.com](http://apple.com). The link works just fine. However, what I'd like to have is the link http://www.apple.com but it is a link displayed as `Apple` or `Foo`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn’t support that, and so neither does the iOS Twitter API. Your link may get shortened to a `http://t.co/something` URL if it’s too long to fit the remaining content of the tweet, but it will always display as a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done I'm afraid. In order for that to work, the tweet would have to contain some kind of markup, which twitter does not support in tweets.

When you insert a link into a tweet, twitter will automatically shorten it if necessary, and use the http://t.co/ url instead of the long one. If the link is short enough, it'll remain unshortened.

The twitter API provides links within tweets as entities separate to the tweet text. This allows twitter clients to do things like custom displaying of links (like how you're thinking), however this can't be used for the other direction (sending tweets to twitter).

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
[twitController setInitialText:@"http://apple.com"]
```

Twitter automatically removes the http header. The text will be converted apple.com as a link.